# could not understand the behavior of read system call

Tags: c, offset, segment, memory-address

So this is the code I am trying to run:

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){

  int ret;

  ret = read(STDIN_FILENO,(int*)2000,3);
  printf("%d--%s\n",ret,strerror(errno));

  return 0;
}
```

and this is the output I get at the terminal

```
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Desktop/testing$ gcc test.c 
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Desktop/testing$ ./a.out 
lls
-1--Bad address
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Desktop/testing$ ls
a.out  htmlget_ori.c  mysocket.cpp  Packet Sniffer.c  resolutionfinder.c  test.c
anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Desktop/testing$
```

**Question 1:** When I type the address 2000 in th read call `read(STDIN_FILENO,(int*)2000,3);` 
then where does the address lies. I think this is the absolute address of the RAM that I am trying to access. am I right or is it offset and is added to the Stack Segment Base Address. I do not know. The program is not giving me a `SEGFAULT` for memory violation rather gives me `Bad address`

**Question 2:** Okay so the code crashes when I give the input as `lls` and bash executes the "ls" part of that "lls". The reason is that the code crashes after reading the first "l" and the rest "ls" part is executed by bash. but why bash is executing the left "ls" part. Why is bash doing so because my code is crashed and even if bash was its parent process it should not read from the file-descriptor (STDIN_FILNO) opened by the code I wrote. ( I think so)...

Thanks for your time.

Comment: "I think this is the absolute address of the RAM that I am trying to access." You think so, based on what information?

Comment: *@Anirudh*: Is there really no better way than specifying a fixed memory location? Could you give some background information about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: why don't you use `read()` normally, i.e. `unsigned char buffer[3]; read(STDIN_FILENO, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running on a CPU with paging. Your OS maintains page tables which translate from virtual to physical addresses. The page table for your process doesn't contain anything for virtual address 2000, so `read()` notices, and returns `-EFAULT`.

`stdin` is connected to your terminal device (`/dev/tty`). Your process inherits that terminal from your shell, and the shell gets it back on process exit.

Answer (score 4):

The `2000` that you are trying to use as an address is a *process-specific* **virtual address**. Chances are good that nothing is mapped into that range; you can add this code to see what your mappings currently are:

```
char cmd[20];

sprintf(cmd, "pmap -x %i", getpid());
printf("%s\n", cmd);
system(cmd);
```

If you really must gain access to *system* RAM around `2000` (and I can't imagine that you are), use the `iopl(2)` system call to map that address range into your process memory space. And beware the consequences. :)

As for the rest of the `ls` behaviour, try adding a `\n` to your `printf()` format string, I've found that not properly flushing output can lead to confusing-looking interaction, perhaps this is just confusing, rather than outright strange. :)

Comment: even when I give it `(int*) 0` it doesn't work. SO if I consider it to be part of my Data Segment then my code should be allowed to read the memory at the offset 0.

Comment: @Anirudh Tomer, most operating systems by default refuse all access to the data page located at `0x0`, as an easy way to find `NULL`-pointer mistakes. Try executing `pmap -x $$` from your shell to get a better idea of how memory mapping works.

Comment: `iopl()` doesn't give access to memory assigned to a lower ring. It gives access to IO ports and to some privileged instructions.